# WPF: Two DataGrids, same ItemsSource, One IsReadOnly, Bug?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, itemssource

I have a WPF application with two DataGrids that share the same ItemsSource.   When I set one of the DataGrid's IsReadOnly property to true, I lose the ability to add records to the other DataGrid.  I can still edit the contents of the second datagrid, but just cannot add records.

Is this intended?  Is there way around this?   I could use IsEnabled="False" for the DataGrid, but I then lose the ability to scroll in it.

Here is the setup:

XAML:

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="dgA" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>         
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgB" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Johnson" });
        persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" });

        dgA.ItemsSource = persons;
        dgB.ItemsSource = persons;
    }

    class Person
    {
        public Person() { }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean add records programmatically (i.e. via C# as in the MainWindow constructor)?

Comment: The DataGrid out of IsReadOnly mode usually has a blank row which can be used to add records.  This blank row is no longer available in this instance.  I have not tried adding records programmatically.

Comment: maybe set the data binding for dgB to oneway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what's going on is that the `IsReadOnly` property is making the `DataGrid` readonly through the DefaultView for `persons`, and since this DefaultView will be the same for both of your `DataGrid's`, both looses the ability to add new rows.

Both doesn't become readonly however (as you said in your question) so I'm not sure if this is a bug or a desired behavior.

I'm also not sure what's going on behind the scenes here that causes this behavior but you can verify that the CollectionView's are the same through the debugger (since the CollectionView property is private). The following three statements come out as true

```
dgA.Items.CollectionView == CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(persons) // true
dgB.Items.CollectionView == CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(persons) // true
dgA.Items.CollectionView == dgB.Items.CollectionView // true
```

You can get it to work the way you like by changing the `List` to an `ObservableCollection` and use separate `ListViewCollection's` for your `DataGrid's`

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Johnson" });
    persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" });

    dgA.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(persons);
    dgB.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(persons);
}
```

Comment: +1 for helping me understand whats going on.  But That doesn't give me the desired functionality.  I would like the second grid to contain everything the first grid does, as well as change whenever the first grid does.  When I edit an item in the first grid, it does change in the second.  But unfortunately, adding or removing records in the first grid does not affect the second grid.

Comment: @Jeff: Did you change the `List` to an `ObservableCollection`? I just tried this and it works for both editing cells and adding/removing rows

Comment: By the way, sort order is also affected... due to the same collection view usage,